# Decode frame from h264 stream to OpenCV Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, streaming, mp4, ar.drone

Product: Bebop
Product version: Software version v2.0.29
SDK version: ARSDK3_version_3_14_0
Use of libARController: Yes
SDK platform: UNIX
Reproductible with the official app: NO

I have been trying to convert an ARCONTROLLER_Frame_t from ARSDK 3 to an OpenCV image using Ubuntu 18.04, originally, the sample program provided made use of MPlayer to open a FIFO, where the program wrote all the frames it received from the drone, I managed to obtain images from said stream using ffmpeg while it was running. I also tried to give OpenCV said file to use as a source for VideoCapture, which worked but was horribly delayed. I am currently trying to give OpenCV frame by frame.

[This is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCrQL.png) of the definition of ARCONTROLLER_Frame_t, the documentation is very vague about how everything works.

I currently get the following image:
[Screen shot of the image obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6pjJ.png)

I previously used this to try to decode it, assuming it was on an RGB format, this image reacts to interaction with the camera, so I assume it is the correct data:

```
void rawToMat(Mat &destImage, ARCONTROLLER_Frame_t &sourceImage) {
  if (sourceImage.used == 0) {
    return;
  }
  uchar *pointerImage = destImage.ptr(0);

  for (int i = 0; i < 480 * 856; i++) {
    pointerImage[3 * i] = sourceImage.data[3 * i + 2];
    pointerImage[3 * i + 1] = sourceImage.data[3 * i + 1];
    pointerImage[3 * i + 2] = sourceImage.data[3 * i];
  }
}
```

But I found out this provided the same output:

```
ARCONTROLLER_Frame_t newFrame = getCurrentFrame();
Mat currentImage = Mat(480, 856, CV_8UC3, newFrame.data);
```

Does someone know a way to get an actual image from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ARCONTROLLER_Frame_t` does not contain an RGB image; it contains an H.264 frame that must be converted to an RGB image using an H.264 decoder (for example, see [this response](https://forum.developer.parrot.com/t/bebop-2-arsdk3-image-processing/6586) on the Parrot developer forum).

This old sample code from Parrot demonstrates how to decode frames using the ffmpeg/libav library (it's much too long to post here): https://github.com/Parrot-Developers/Samples/tree/59b6ba5cdc268fb6932d228db7b9169d9b69384c/Unix/BebopDroneDecodeStream

Comment: Thanks! Will give it a look, I was researching and Im already trying to use libav